# Backslashes in MySql update query not working

Tags: mysql, backslash

Running the following query in MySql workbench as \ is an escape character.

```
UPDATE midshared.SETUP
SET DATAVALUE = 'C:\Documents and Settings\ADMINISTRATOR\Desktop\'
WHERE CODE = 'SAGEPATH'
```

manually changing to this does work.

```
UPDATE midshared.SETUP
SET DATAVALUE = 'C:\\Documents and Settings\\ADMINISTRATOR\\Desktop\\'
WHERE CODE = 'SAGEPATH'
```

However trying these methods that I've found on Stack Overflow don't work either -

```
UPDATE midshared.SETUP
SET DATAVALUE = REPLACE('C:\Settings\ADMINISTRATOR\Desktop\','\','\\')
WHERE CODE = 'SAGEPATH'
```

or

```
UPDATE midshared.SETUP
SET DATAVALUE = QUOTE('C:\Documents and Settings\ADMINISTRATOR\Desktop\')
WHERE CODE = 'SAGEPATH'
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction to fix it please?
Thanks
A

I tried the queries listed above

Answer (score 0):

You can use double quotes safely and escape slashes as follows:

```
UPDATE midshared.SETUP
SET DATAVALUE = "'C:\\Documents and Settings\\ADMINISTRATOR\\Desktop\\'"
WHERE CODE_ = 'SAGEPATH'
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6C65znMrBW3LEWtQBhwZ7g/0).

Comment: 17:38:14 UPDATE setup SET DATAVALUE = "'C:\Documents and Settings\ADMINISTRATOR\Desktop\'" WHERE CODE_ = 'SAGEPATH' Error Code: 1046. No database selected Select the default DB to be used by double-clicking its name in the SCHEMAS list in the sidebar. 0.031 sec

Comment: Thanks for the answer but workbench doesn't like the formatting. Also, I'm trying not to manually write the double slashes as the actual data only has single slashes.

Comment: Sorry, that's a completely different error my mistake. I;ll try again

Comment: You should read your error first. It's telling you that you need to select a database to run the query.

Comment: That stripped all the slashes and also wrote quotes around the data

Comment: Double slashes are always stripped when you copy-paste. You can add them manually and try if it works for you or doesn't.